# Manual bootstrapping with Juju on VPS

Tags: juju

I recently bought a VPS (OpenVZ) with Ubuntu 13.04. Lately I've read about Juju and I thought it would match my needs on my brand new VPS as I want to easily configure Hadoop, Wordpress, Graphite and other services.

I tried the juju-local approach but I got an error while installing it:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/6373143/

So I got to #juju IRC channel and I was told to use "Manual bootstrapping" and create a question here in order to get more info as it seems is something under development.

Could anybody help me getting Juju to work on my VPS? Did any had the same problem?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
After some more research (and after reading my own question) I think I should clarify a little more the situation.

What I want is a manual provider to allow me manage my VPS from Juju. I know there might be a work in progress and I would appreciate any info regarding it's state and any possible solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Juju 1.16.0 has preliminary support for manual provisioning, and a manual provider. Unfortunately we found quite late (too late for inclusion in 1.16.0) that there were a number of bugs that made it quite difficult to use. For this reason, we've not announced this widely yet.

If you're going to try it, I'd suggest either waiting for 1.17.0 (or later), or if you're adventurous, build from source. There's only one known bug now (discounting those caused by it), and that's that you can't destroy the environment (uninstall the agents) via the juju tool.

Everything in the [docs](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/config-manual.html) is still true right now, but may change as we develop things. It is quite likely the name of the provider ("null") will change, for instance. If you have more specific questions after reading the docs, please update your question.